# How to create a multiple recipes by looping over a Makefile list?

Tags: shell, makefile, rules, recipe

I have the following makefile that has multiple `cp` commands to copy directories from source to destination.

```
process:
   cp dir/level/2000/config.json output/2000/config.json
   cp dir/level/2001/config.json output/2001/config.json
   cp dir/level/2002/config.json output/2002/config.json

stage:
   mkdir -p output/2000 output/2001 output/2002
   cp dir/common/2000/esc output/2000/esc
   cp dir/common/2001/esc output/2001/esc
   cp dir/common/2002/esc output/2002/esc

apply: stage process
```

I want to make the above Makefile more dynamic by introducing a variable list of `2000 2001 2002` and it would then loop over the variable and run the rule every iteration. Something like...

```
var := 2000 2001 2002
process:
   cp dir/level/${var}/config.json output/${var}/config.json

stage:
   mkdir -p output/${var}
   cp dir/common/${var}/esc output/${var}/esc

apply: stage process
```

Now if I run `make apply` it should recreate the same steps as the first makefile.
I tried using multiple targets as `${var}` and it worked the way I wanted but it can only be used in place of one of the targets, not for both `stage` and `process`. I did

```
process:
   cp dir/level/2000/config.json output/2000/config.json
   cp dir/level/2001/config.json output/2001/config.json
   cp dir/level/2002/config.json output/2002/config.json

${var}:
   mkdir -p output/$@ 
   cp dir/common/$@/esc output/$@/esc

apply: ${var} process
```

Now if I run make apply, it will run as I expected but how to use the same multiple targets in place of `process` too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would use pattern rules most likely:

```
apply: stage process

var := 2000 2001 2002

process: $(foreach V,$(var),output/$V/config.json)
stage: $(foreach V,$(var),output/$V/esc)

output/%/config.json: dir/level/%/config.json
        cp $< $@

output/%/esc : dir/common/%/esc
        mkdir -p $(@D)
        cp $< $@
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution is probably to use a shell `for` loop in your recipe:

```
var := 2000 2001 2002

process:
  for year in $(var); do \
    cp dir/level/$$year/config.json output/$$year/config.json; \
  done
```

Note that within the recipe we need to write `$$year` to refer to the
shell variable named `year` because a single `$` would introduce a
makefile variable reference.

---

Using just `make` syntax, you could do this:

```
var = 2000 2001 2002
outputs = $(patsubst %,output/%/config.json,$(var))

output/%/config.json: dir/level/%/config.json
    echo cp $< $@

all: $(outputs)
```

This creates a variable `outputs` that has the content:

```
output/2000/config.json output/2001/config.json output/2002/config.json
```

And then uses a pattern rule to implicitly create recipes for creating those outputs from the corresponding inputs.

Comment: I want to avoid using shell, want to use the make's declarative syntax only. I have updated the question and added one of the approaches that I used, can you take a look?